# How to set ng-disabled to false on specific button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a fieldset that sets ng-disabled to true or false based on certain conditions.

```
<fieldset class="panel-body" ng-disabled="CoreFormPartVI.overview.UserReadOnly     || CoreFormPartVI.overview.Locked">
```

I have a button that I want to be enabled regardless of this fieldset.

```
excel-definition="CoreFormPartVI.PartVIRelationshipDefinition" ng-disabled="readOnly"
                            ></div>
```

I tried setting ng-disabled="false" on the button, but that doesn't seem to work.  Is there a way to say, disable everything except that specific button?

Comment: The disabled attribute causes all the form control descendants of the fieldset element to be disabled (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-fieldset-element.html#attr-fieldset-disabled). I'm afraid you have to enable/disable every element individually

Comment: @mrak, Thanks for the advice.  This helped me figure out how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't solve your problem, you might not want to use a fieldset  with ng-disabled since it doesn't work in IE (even 11).

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_fieldset_disabled.asp

I suggest you disable every element induvidually (bound to the same scope variable for easy triggering).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I left the fieldset as disabled, but instead turn the button into an a element and used css to make it look like a button.  There are a lof of pages that would need to be edited if I went with applying the disabled to each individual element.  This way I can just target the one button.